# ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My model is defined as below:

```
def build(data):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((79, 145), (50, 250)), input_shape= 
                                                                   (160,320,3)))
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5 - 1.0))

    model.add(Conv2D(24, (2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(ELU())
    model.add(Conv2D(36, (2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(ELU())
    model.add(Conv2D(48, (2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(ELU())

    # Add a flatten layer
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.summary()
    model.add(Dense(100))
    model.add(ELU())
    model.add(Dense(50))
    model.add(ELU())
    model.add(Dense(10))
    model.add(ELU())
    model.add(Dense(1))

    return model
```

Getting this error:

> ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be
>   defined. Found `None`.

I ran `model.summary()` and got the following output

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cropping2d_15 (Cropping2D)   (None, 0, 20, 3)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_23 (Lambda)           (None, 0, 20, 3)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_47 (Conv2D)           (None, 0, 20, 24)         312       
_________________________________________________________________
elu_43 (ELU)                 (None, 0, 20, 24)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_48 (Conv2D)           (None, 0, 20, 36)         3492      
_________________________________________________________________
elu_44 (ELU)                 (None, 0, 20, 36)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_49 (Conv2D)           (None, 0, 20, 48)         6960      
_________________________________________________________________
elu_45 (ELU)                 (None, 0, 20, 48)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_12 (Flatten)         (None, None)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 10,764
Trainable params: 10,764
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I am fairly new to python, any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: My question here is why is Flatten layer giving an output of (None, None).

Answer (score 3):

You are cropping your input image too much. The `cropping` argument is [interpreted](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#Cropping2D) as follows:

> If tuple of 2 tuples of 2 ints: interpreted as  ((top_crop,
>   bottom_crop), (left_crop, right_crop))

Consider the following example from the Keras docs:

```
# Crop the input 2D images or feature maps
model = Sequential()
model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((2, 2), (4, 4)),
                     input_shape=(28, 28, 3)))
# now model.output_shape == (None, 24, 20, 3)
```

In your code, **you are cropping 79 pixels from the top and 145 pixels from the bottom, whereas the height of your images is only 160 pixels**. With less cropping, your code runs fine, eg:

```
model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((10, 10), (10, 10)), input_shape=(160,320,3)))
```